# Render thymeleaf fragment without page refresh on post

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf fragment that contains user profile edit form. Upon form submission I want to load the fragment with the latest data without page refresh. To do that, I have this following controller method -

```
@PostMapping("/profile/settings")
public String update(@ModelAttribute Contact contact, ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

    //db call and other stuffs
    model.put("contact", loggedInUser.getContact());

    if (result.hasError()) {
        model.put("error", errorMsg);
    }

    return "fragments/contents/editProfile :: editProfile";
}
```

accountSettings.html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <editProfile th:replace="~{fragments/contents/editProfile :: editProfile(${contact}, ${error})}"></editProfile>
    </body>
</html>
```

#editProfile.html fragment

```
<editProfile th:fragment="editProfile(account, error)" id="editProfile">

    <div id="account_settings_profile_details">
        <form th:action="@{/profile/settings}"
                  th:object="${contact}"
                  method="post"
                  id="account_profile_details_form"
                  class="form">

            <input type="text" name="fname" th:field="*{first_name}" />

            <button type="submit" id="account_profile_details_submit">Save Changes</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/

        document.getElementById('account_profile_details_form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);            
            var action = this.closest("form").getAttribute("action");

            fetch(action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            }).then(response => {
                return response.text();
            }).then(data => {
                var error = /*[[${error}]]*/ 'null';
                
                document.getElementById('editProfile').outerHTML = data;
            }).catch(error => console.error('Error submitting form:', error));
        });
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</editProfile>
```

The first post request executes well but from the second attempt I got the following error at the browser console -

> //net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

on second post request
and all the styling vanishes and only the fragment code appears without other fragments.

What may cause this issue? Or is there any better approach to achieve this feature with thymeleafe?

p.s. I have also tried converting the controller method to a rest endpoint with `@ResponseBody` returning `ResponseEntity<>` by processing the fragment inside the method using thymeleaf `TemplateEngine`. But with that approach parse error (form binding) occurs.